# AngularJS JSONP $http params 'Unexpected token''

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I have a JSONP problem in AngularJS. It works when there are no params necessary, but returns an 'unexpected token' error as soon as there are more params than the mandatory "callback:JSON_CALLBACK"

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

/* this works */
$http({method: 'JSONP', 
          params:{'callback':'JSON_CALLBACK'}, 
          url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/paris'}).success(function(data) {
              $scope.fbchannel = data

           }).error(function(err) {
                 console.log(err);
          });

/* this works not: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  */
     $http({method: 'JSONP', 
            params:{'callback':'JSON_CALLBACK', 'address':'Paris', 'sensor':'false'},                               
    url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'}).success(function(data) {
              $scope.gmaps = data

    }).error(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think the error is because googleapi is returning JSON instead of JSONP. You might want to re-check their api to get JSONP.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find another call in the docs. I also tried with different APIs. I always get this error message when I provide http params. It's not only related to the Google API.